# How do I enable logging of successful authorizations in keystone?

Tags: logging, openstack, keystone, openstack-keystone

Can you tell me how to enable successful authorization events in keystone? I have studied the documentation, but it only says that these events are disabled by default. I tried specifying the notification = identity.authenticate.success parameter in the keystone.conf file, but it didn't give any result. I have enabled the cadf notification format to get an extended event view. I get user creation events, projects, etc. in the logs, but I don't get authorization events. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what kind of drive are u using for oslo_messaging_notifications?

Comment: I specified driver = log

Comment: did you enable journal or not? you can check journal too . actually i use rabbit for this purpose.

Comment: you can enable debug = True. to see all logs.

Comment: @Aref When you enable debug mode, a lot of unnecessary messages appear in the log file, I would like to see only what is really needed

Comment: you are right. but there is not a option under oslo_messaging_notifications to set log level for that.

Answer (score 0):

Set as below will enable identity.authenticate.*:

keystone.conf:

```
[DEFAULT]
notification_opt_out =
...
```

Then restart keystone service to apply your changes.